# WPF How to execute command from Main ViewModel to a child ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using MVVM. I have a tabcontrol and numbers of button in my MainView.
When I click some button it will load child view in tabitem. This child view also having tabcontrol.
Now when I click to some other button the sub child view should be loaded in to childview tabcontrol as tabitem.

What is the best practice for setting up a navigation like this?

I don't want to use EventAggregator. Is there another way to do this?

So how to execute command in child view to load sub child view in child tabcontrol as tabitem from mainview or main window?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use **[Composite Commands](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Working-with-Prism-4-Part-3-Composite-Command-and-Pub-Sub-Events.aspx)**.
 Make the button commands composite, and have the  child view **[register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec3)** to those commands

By the way, is there a specific reason for not wanting to work with the EventAggregator?